# jQuery MultiSelect can not enable a disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I have several dropdowns, only one of them is enabled from the beginning on, all others are disabled 
        `<select class="someClass" name="someName" multiple id="someId" disabled>`

the enabling of the disabled drop-downs depends on the selection of the values in the very first (enabled) dropdown, so I use the following code

```
$('#enabledDropDown').on('change',function() { }
```

in there (in a further if statement) I tried every possible combinations of:

```
$('#someId').multiselect('enable');
$('#someId').multiselect('refresh');
$('#someId option').attr('disabled',false);
$('#someId').prop('disabled', false);
$('#someId').material_select();
$('#someId').removeAttr('disabled');
```

but it just not works. The dropdown remains disabled!

**EDIT:**
I have a `$(document).ready(function () {  }`
which does the following...

```
$('#someId').multiselect({
    name : 'someName',
    columns : someNumber,
    placeholder : 'somePlaceholder'

 });
```

this seems to be the cause to my problem, because if I remove the corresponding code block in the document.ready function the drop-down behaves as expected.
The problem is I need that document.ready function.

I dont really understand why this interacts because the document.ready is executed only once when the side loads. But the enabling happens after that.

Comment: try `$('#someId').attr('disabled', false);`

Comment: where those `multiselect` `material_select` came from? some plugin? if so probably the docs will have some information about it

Comment: did you tried  `$("#someId").slideToggle();`

Comment: if possible create a snippet or fiddler.

Comment: if its multiple then it should be <select class="someClass" name="someName[]" multiple="multiple" id="someId" disabled> to get selected values in array

Comment: Or remove the attribute with jquery $("#someId").removeAttr("disabled");

Answer (score 0):

Check your condition once again. `prop('disable',false)` should work, check below snippet for reference.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkMe").click(function() {
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
          $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", true);
       } else {
          $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", false);  
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown" style="width:200px;">
              <option value="feedback">Options</option>
              <option value="feedback">Options</option>
              </select>

              <input type="checkbox" id="checkMe" value="feedback"/>Check me!
```

Comment: the condition is fine, the cause is described in the edit section, thx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
document.getElementById("someId").disabled=false;
```

and add a onclick function on first dropdown and check for its value and then enable / disable the dropdown.

```js
function check(){
  if(document.getElementById('enabledDropDown').value == 'someId')
    document.getElementById('someId').disabled=false;
  else
    document.getElementById('someId').disabled=true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form>
    <text>Select someId to enable dropdown</text><br>
    
    <select class="someClass" name="someName" id="enabledDropDown" onchange="check()">
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>Orange</option>
      <option>someId</option>
      <option>Pear</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>Orange</option>
    </select>

    <select class="someClass" name="someName" id="someId" disabled>
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Pear</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>Orange</option>
    </select>
    
    
    <br><br>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use $(".someClass").prop("disabled", false); This is work. Example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function check() {
        $(".someClass").prop("disabled", false);
    }

</script>
<form>
   <select class="someClass" name="someName" id="enabledDropDown" onchange="check()">
        <option>Data1</option>
        <option>Data2</option>
 </select>
    <br>
    <select class="someClass" name="someName" multiple id="someId" disabled>
        <option>Data3</option>
        <option>Data4</option>
        <option>Data5</option>
        <option>Data6</option>
        <option>Data7</option>
        <option>Data8</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select class="someClass" name="someName" multiple id="someId2" disabled>
        <option>Data9</option>
        <option>Data10</option>
        <option>Data11</option>
        <option>Data12</option>
        <option>Data13</option>
        <option>Data14</option>
    </select>
</form>
```